# Транслитерация строки из кирилици на латиницу и наоборот php

Tags: php

В данный момент у меня есть функция, которая переводит строку в транслит:

```
function rus2translit($string) {
    $converter = array(
        'а' => 'a',   'б' => 'b',   'в' => 'v',
        'г' => 'g',   'д' => 'd',   'е' => 'e',
        'ё' => 'e',   'ж' => 'zh',  'з' => 'z',
        'и' => 'i',   'й' => 'y',   'к' => 'k',
        'л' => 'l',   'м' => 'm',   'н' => 'n',
        'о' => 'o',   'п' => 'p',   'р' => 'r',
        'с' => 's',   'т' => 't',   'у' => 'u',
        'ф' => 'f',   'х' => 'h',   'ц' => 'c',
        'ч' => 'ch',  'ш' => 'sh',  'щ' => 'sch',
        'ь' => '',  'ы' => 'y',   'ъ' => '',
        'э' => 'e',   'ю' => 'yu',  'я' => 'ya',

        'А' => 'A',   'Б' => 'B',   'В' => 'V',
        'Г' => 'G',   'Д' => 'D',   'Е' => 'E',
        'Ё' => 'E',   'Ж' => 'Zh',  'З' => 'Z',
        'И' => 'I',   'Й' => 'Y',   'К' => 'K',
        'Л' => 'L',   'М' => 'M',   'Н' => 'N',
        'О' => 'O',   'П' => 'P',   'Р' => 'R',
        'С' => 'S',   'Т' => 'T',   'У' => 'U',
        'Ф' => 'F',   'Х' => 'H',   'Ц' => 'C',
        'Ч' => 'Ch',  'Ш' => 'Sh',  'Щ' => 'Sch',
        'Ь' => '',  'Ы' => 'Y',   'Ъ' => '',
        'Э' => 'E',   'Ю' => 'Yu',  'Я' => 'Ya',
    );
    return strtr($string, $converter);
  }
```

Помогите пожалуйста создать обратную функцию. К примеру **translit2rus()**

Либо же как то изменить текущую функцию где вторым параметром передавать вариант транслитерации.

Мне нужно что бы функция

```
translit2rus("ispaniya") венрула: испания
```

**Обновление вопроса**

Функция конвертирования в обратную кодировку нужна была для того, что у меня есть запрос:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE name = '$country'");
```

В данный момент в БД name на русском. $country прилетает транслитом. Как мне тогда лучше всего провести сравнение, что бы было минимум запросов? Можно ли налету в запросе name перевести с помощью функции в транслит?

Comment: С подобной кодировкой вряд ли получится, потому что без искусственного интеллекта как вы отличите "Chinvali" от "Chaika"? "Shoronit" от "shakal"? "Schet" от "Schit"? "Tygydym" от "yarkiy"? В конце концов, почему в вашем примере не должна быть возвращена "испаниыа"?

Comment: Если верить мануалу на функцию, то вроде бы как достаточно "перевернуть" ключи и значения в `$converter`... [Справка по strtr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php): *strtr() в первую очередь заменяет более длинные ключи, причем одна и та же строка поиска используется только один раз.*

Comment: Я обновил свой вопрос и дополнил его контекстом, для чего мне нужна была эта функция. Возможно вы сможете помочь решить задачу по другому?

Comment: Можно попробовать "перевернуть" ключи значения, посмотреть что получится:)

Comment: Однако не понятно как быть с мягким и твердым знаками. В транслит они возвращают "" а наоборот их применить получается не получится

Comment: *не понятно как быть с мягким и твердым знаками* Их придётся исключить из таблицы. А ещё лучше - взять транслитерационную таблицу не с потолка, а, скажем, из ГОСТа.

Comment: Простите еще за супер оффтоп. А есть какие то варианты вывода переменной в php в таком варианте: echo ($param1 | $param2); если к примеру будет значение в первой или во второй переменнов. Без тернарного оператора?

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте ход конём: создайте таблицу translations из трёх значащих столбцов: country_id, language, translation, наполняйте её и выбирайте из неё:

`SELECT b.translation FROM countries a, translations b WHERE a.id = b.country_id AND b.language='russian' AND a.country = 'ispaniya';`

Заодно и проблемы с локализацией на другие языки решите :)

Comment: Как вариант, спасибо. Но перевода не будет на сайте, поэтому просто добавлю поле и все страны которые есть переведу в транслит и сохраню значения в бд.